# Does SailsJS support ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to get [ES6](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) in [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a node.js question not specifically sails. Yes current version of node.js support certain ES2015 standards depending on your Node.js version and flags you use when you start your server.

Most features are already active, however to use all features, you would use `node app.js --es_staging` or  `node app.js --harmony` in your project folder instead of `sails lift`

The following link provides updated information on what features current version of Node support and how to access them.

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

Answer (score 15):

SailsJS is just a framework written via ES5 syntax and it doesn't need to support ES6.

You can write project with ES6 syntax as you usually do and use Babel\Traceur\whatever for running.

My flow is following:

- Create Sails project;
- Install `babel` as `devDependencies`;
- Update `npm start` script in `package.json` with `"start": "babel-node app.js"`;

That's it. I can write ES6\7 code in my controllers\models\etc and run the server via `npm start` command. It works as usual as you wrote it with ES5 syntax.

[Babel Transpiler](https://babeljs.io)

[Babel Node](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node)

Comment: Not so easy unfortunately. Error thrown: 
/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:415
      var hasStack = (arguments[1] && arguments[1].stack);
                                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Comment: Now as ESM exists, it requires support by build chains and frameworks, otherwise `"type": "module"` can't be used correctly. babel/typescript needs to generate `import` and no `require`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to check compatibility of ES6 with node.js instead any framework like  sails.js, express etc.

Because at last node.js will change the javaScript to server side code.
So it doesn't matter which framework you are using.

> You can use the sails with ES6:

For ES6 compatibility check [kangax.github.io](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Recommended :

> [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/) v 0.11.0 or greater
>
> [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) v 4.*.* or greater
>
> [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) v 2.14.4 or greater

Now you are ready to explore new [Ecmascript6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla) feature.

You will get the new feature from [http://es6-features.org/](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis).

TEST :

Code:

```
ecma6Test:function(req,res,next){
    var evens =req.body.evens
    odds  = evens.map(v => v + 1);
    res.json({sucess:true,'odds':odds});
}
```

Request:

```
{"evens":[2,4,6,8,10]}
```

Response :

```
{
    "sucess": true,
    "odds":[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
}
```

Comment: Staged features are not considered stable by the V8 team. but you can user them by --harmony flag. But I think you have to wait until they are stable.

Comment: Now as ESM exists, it requires support by build chains and frameworks, otherwise `"type": "module"` can't be used correctly. babel/typescript needs to generate `import` and no `require`.

Answer (score 2):

Vishnu's answer has you covered.

The explicit list of ES6 features available in the latest node release is here https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

> Which ES6 features ship with Node.js by default (no runtime flag required)?

- let (strict mode only)
- const
- function-in-blocks (strict mode only)

  - As of v8 3.31.74.1, block-scoped declarations are intentionally implemented with a non-compliant limitation to strict mode code. Developers should be aware that this will change as v8 continues towards ES6 specification compliance.
- Classes (strict mode only)
- Collections
- Map
- WeakMap
- Set
- WeakSet
- Typed arrays
- Generators
- Binary and Octal literals
- Object literal extensions (shorthand properties and methods)
- Promises
- New String methods
- Symbols
- Template strings
- Arrow Functions

Answer (score 1):

There is the [sails-hook-babel](https://github.com/sane/sails-hook-babel) hook that might work out for you. It doesn't work for me, as I explain below, but I hope it gets higher visibility, is improved, and then this answer will be more relevant.

Currently, as of v6.0.1 the library will work for files loaded after the sails hooks run. This means that if you want to use ES2015 in e.g. your `config/routes.js` file, you will get a syntax error. But as suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/sane/sails-hook-babel/issues/7), it should work for e.g. files in the `api` folder.